# Why doesn't my defined delete function working proberly in python? all results are deleted

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a program that stores data in a text file, I can search for data line by line, and I made a (delete function) that is quoted below, making a variable 'a' adding to it the (non deleted lines), and ask before deletion for results and if not confirmed it would be added also to 'a', then rewrite the (file) with'a' omitting the deleted lines.

THE PROBLEM IS:
  all results are deleted not only the confirmed one desbite that:

```
#deleting line
                confirm = input('confirm to delete [y]/[n]>>')
                if confirm != 'y':
                   a += line
```

so, why did this problem happen and how to fix it?
Next is the whole code of delete function:

```
searching = input('enter any information about query: ')
    searching = searching.lower() # converting words in lower case
    f = open(file, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    print('Word | Definition | Remarks')
    a = ''      # we will store our new edited text here
    for line in lines:

        line_lower_case = line.lower() # changing line in lower case temporary
        # because contact != COntact and will not appear in searcch
        if searching in line_lower_case:
            print('Query found')
            print()
            print('>>',line, end = '') # printing words in the same case as been added
            # end = '', to prevent printing new line avoiding extra empty line

            #deleting line
            confirm = input('confirm to delete [y]/[n]>>')
            if confirm != 'y':
               a += line         
            #elif confirm =='y':
               # pass          # it will just do nothing, and will not add line to 'a' 

            continue          # to search for more queries with the same searching entry
            print()



        a += line         #we add each line to the 'a' variable

        f = open(file,'w')
        f.write(a)        #we save our new edited text to the file
        f.close()
```

Comment: Indentation appears to be the problem. You write on every loop which will overwrite each time. Deindent open, write and close and that should solve your problem

Comment: It is better to use a list to collect the lines instead of concatenating the string (which is very inefficient because of the immutability of the string type in Python). Use `lst = []` to initialize (empty list instead of  `a = ''`), `lst.append(line)` instead of your `a += line`, and `f.write(''.join(lst))` to reconstruct and write the result to the output file.

Comment: thank you, it worked fine now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the indentations of the program and that was the issue as I agreed with @TheLazyScripter and that should work now if I understood your problem correctly, I did a bunch of tests and they did work. I noticed that you didn't define what input file will be and I add that line of code at line 3 which will through an error if the file not defined.

```
searching = input('enter any information about query: ')
searching = searching.lower() # converting words in lower case
file = "test.txt" #your file
f = open(file, 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()
print('Word | Definition | Remarks')
a = ''      # we will store our new edited text here
for line in lines:
    line_lower_case = line.lower() # changing line in lower case temporary
    # because contact != COntact and will not appear in searcch
    if searching in line_lower_case:
        print('Query found')
        print()
        print('>>',line, end = '') # printing words in the same case as been added
        # end = '', to prevent printing new line avoiding extra empty line

        #deleting line
        confirm = input('confirm to delete [y]/[n]>>')
        if confirm != 'y':
           a += line
        #elif confirm =='y':
           # pass          # it will just do nothing, and will not add line to 'a'

        continue          # to search for more queries with the same searching entry
        print()



    a += line         #we add each line to the 'a' variable

    f = open(file,'w')
    f.write(a)        #we save our new edited text to the file
    f.close()
```

Comment: TheLazyScripter meant to deindent the last three lines -- these are repeated in the for loop body, and they should not.

Comment: It worked for me. Thanks. The file is not defined here.  It is present in tha first line that wasn't included here def delete(file).then I made a main menu "main(filename.txt")  to avoid repetetion.